# Python3.8 Flask wsgi on apache2 error: "Fatal Python error: ... No module named 'encodings'"

Tags: python-3.x, linux, apache, wsgi

I am attempting to configure a flask website on Ubuntu 18.04 using python3.8. I am following a few tutorials for configuring everything but I have hit a stopping point when I encounter the following error in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[Sat Feb 08 18:29:08.089321 2020] [wsgi:warn] [pid 16992:tid 140217694870464] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=16992): Unable to stat Python home Xeplin/venv. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'Xeplin/venv'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = 'Xeplin/venv'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'Xeplin/venv'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = 'Xeplin/venv'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'Xeplin/venv'
  sys.path = [
    'Xeplin/venv/lib/python38.zip',
    'Xeplin/venv/lib/python3.8',
    'Xeplin/venv/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I have found a lot of unique answers for similar situations but none of them seem to eliminate this error.

I have attempted opening all permissions on the virtual env, opening permissions on my entire folder structure, and a few other things that I essentially copy and pasted from various stackoverflow threads.

This is my first time doing all of this so I am not sure what files are relevant for fixing this issue. I will provide a few things here.

`tail /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.conf`

```
    #The WSGILazyInitialization directives sets whether or not the Python
    #interpreter is preinitialised within the Apache parent process or whether
    #lazy initialisation is performed, and the Python interpreter only
    #initialised in the Apache server processes or mod_wsgi daemon processes
    #after they have forked from the Apache parent process.

        #WSGILazyInitialization On|Off

</IfModule>
WSGIPythonHome "/home/ubuntu/Xeplin/venv"
```

(I have added the python home here. Rest of the file is default)

`cat /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load`

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi-py38.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
```

If previous debugging efforts may impact my getting of this error, I previously had to install mod_wsgi which failed when my virtual env was active but worked after deactivating. After running `python3.8 -m pip install mod_wsgi` outside my venv I was able to run `pip install mod_wsgi` inside the env. I found that peculiar so I am mentioning it here.